# Manipulate Dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have dict like this:

```
d = {'A1': 200,
 'A2': 150,
 'A3': 100}
```

I want to multiply each element by 2 but the newvalue can't be more than 300. for above example my output will be..

```
d_final = {'A1': 300,
 'A2': 300,
 'A3': 200}
```

Can this be done using lambda or map??

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do a dict comprehension.

```
d_final = {k: min(2*v, 300) for k,v in d.items()}
```

Comment: this does not work btw

Comment: Fixed the typo. @KnightKnight

Comment: there must `k:` not `k,`

Comment: Cool now @AnkurSaxena

Comment: Can also use `min(2*v, 300)` for value. :)

Comment: @ks2bmallik that is a great idea!